# Link generation not creating proper links to and within area

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razorengine

I have an ASP.NET Core project with only one area called `Data`. The default `Home` controller is still in no area.

### Problem

The linking to the area `Data` in the project does not work. The routing works fine though.

If I manually enter the link *localhost/Data* I get the correct action `Index` of the controller `Home` of the area `Data`. So the routing definitely works.

However `<a asp-area="Data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Data</a>` gets evaluated to the link *localhost/?area=Data*, which does not work and should actually be *localhost/Data*.

Links within the area `Data` are also not evaluating properly. What should be *localhost/Data/Controller* is just *localhost/Controller*. Again manually entering the link works fine.

### Configurations

How I configured the project so far to try and get the links working:
 - Routes are added as follows

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // Default Route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    // Area Route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

- All controllers within the `Data` have the attribute `[Area("Data")]`.
- Added a TagHelper `_ViewImport.cshtml` in *Areas/Data/Views* `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`.

I in general tried to follow the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1), but nothing appears to work.

### Question

So I obviously would like to get the links working without "hardcoding" them and am wondering why the intended behaviour does not seem to work.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of your routes. You should start with more specific routes and then to more general routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // More specific area route
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "areas",
       template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    // Any other (default)
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
```

});

Comment: That was it, thanks!
The documentation I linked did not mention that, it is only mentioned in the [documentation about routing itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1).